# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16d0f3ff0) when append to string

Tags: swift, string, linked-list, append, apple-watch

When running a sample code like this I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when idx reaches >63000 on the line `data_string.append(contentsOf: "\(timestamp), \(X)\n")`:

```
    let accelerometerData = recorder.accelerometerData(from: startOfDay, to: NSDate() as Date)
    var data_string = ""
    for (idx, data) in (accelerometerData?.enumerated())! {
         if let accData = data as? CMRecordedAccelerometerData{
             let accX = accData.acceleration.x
             data_string.append(contentsOf: "\(timestamp), \(accX)\n")

             if idx % 45000 == 0 {
                 let path_to_file = DocumentURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName + "-" + String(idx)).appendingPathExtension("txt")
                 try? data_string.data(using: .utf8)?.write(to: path_to_file)
                 self.sendFile(file_path:path_to_file as NSURL)
                 data_string = ""
             }
             
         }
     }
```

Seems like after putting the string to "" there is still some memory issue happening. Does anyone know how to this better?

When I comment out the string_data and the append I still get the error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This code doesn't make sense. What is `Data`? It must be something you've defined that overrides the standard type of that name. And it's optional on line 2 but then somehow not optional later?

Comment: Code 2 means that pointer is valid but cannot accept the operation you are trying to perform on it. Maybe you are running out of memory? Try to keep the same code, but write something like 1 character into string (e.g. `data_string.append(contentsOf: "a")` - does it still crash?

Comment: hmm same issue even when I comment out the append to string...

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. My guess is it is a timing issue

Comment: There is too much code that doesn't really relate to the issue here. Where is startOfDay property coming from?

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot shows the bad access on this line

```
for (idx, data) in (accelerometerData?.enumerated())! {
```

Are you sure that `accelerometerData` is not nil? You are using `!` to force unwrap it.

Comment: In my testing, if you force unwrap a `nil` value, the underline is under the offending `!`, and the stop reason is: `Swift runtime failure: force unwrapped a nil value`, so I'd suggest this isn't the reason ✌

Comment: And I'm fairly sure that under arm64 in release builds a force unwrap of `nil` would result in hitting a `trap` instruction ✌